# Find out client-side ID of HTML element created by .NET?

Tags: asp.net

How do I write some client-side script to access a HTML element when .NET has generated the element's ID at runtime?

At present I have this in my ASPX:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="middle_area" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="ImageBarChart" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<script>
var oImage = document.getElementById('ctl00_middle_area_ImageBarChart')
</script>
```

It it working at present, but I doubt it is reliable!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ClientID: [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)

You would then do `<%= ImageBarChart.ClientID %>` to put it in your javascript

Comment: God webforms is aweful, nuke it from orbit.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `<%= ImageBarChart.ClientID %>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="middle_area" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="ImageBarChart" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<script>
var oImage = document.getElementById('<%= ImageBarChart.ClientID %>')
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ASP.NET elements Client Id like so:

```
<%= ImageBarChart.ClientID %>
```