# Javascript: How to check if a DropDownList is disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This function check if the the DropDownList is disabled.

```
function CheckRowBeforeSaving() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++) {
      if (e.id.indexOf("_ddlTask") != -1) {
         var disabled = e.disabled;
          alert(disabled);
    }
  }
}
```

I've noticed that when the DropDownList is enabled, the alert box appears with the message "**False**". When the DropDownList is disabled, the alert message does not even appear. How to solve that problem?

## EDIT

I've removed the condition but the result is still the same.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I can't see definition for `e`. If it is some global variable, the whole loop is useless. Maybe you need `var e=document.forms[0][i]` before checking the `id` of it.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET and this code is working.

Comment: Please check `alert(e)` before `if`, what you get?

Comment: Try putting an else clause on your if() statement with another alert.  perhaps ASP.NET is not sending back the index you're expecting?

Comment: @Dan Pichelman, it looks to me that there's an error when the DDL is disabled. In fact, I added an extra alert. And when the DDL is disabled, both alert do not show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've noticed that when the DropDownList is enabled, the alert box appears with the message "False". When the DropDownList is disabled, the alert message does not even appear. How to solve that problem?

Remove the condition that only checks for disabled==false since is already disabled (disabled=true)

```
if (disabled == false) { // <-----REMOVE THIS LINE
       alert(disabled);
}
```

Comment: I've removed the condition but I'm still not getting the alert when the DropDownList is disabled

Comment: how do you disable the select element? via `<select disabled="disabled">`?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET _ddlTask.Enabled = false. When I check page source, I see "select disabled="disabled".

Comment: @Richard77 post your aspx markup and I'll see how can I assist you better.

Comment: I don't know for whichever reason now it's working. Javascript alert is showing wheither the DropDoenList is disabled. I can't explain.

Comment: Believe I must have mistaped something. I work more with server side code, so I'm not acustomed with JS. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (disabled == false) {
            alert(disabled);
         }
```

with just `alert(disabled);`

That is remove the check for disabled

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776789/find-out-client-side-id-of-html-element-created-by-net) -- ASP.NET assigns its own client IDs

You may need

```
function CheckRowBeforeSaving() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++) {
      if (e.id.indexOf('<%= myDDL.ClientID %>') != -1) {
          var disabled = e.disabled;
          alert(disabled);
        }
      }
}
```