# Kendo UI Mobile - Use button to click another button

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

In the following scenario:

**HTML**

```
<a id="mButton" data-role="button" data-click="clickFn">myButton</a>

<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="aspButton" style="display: none"></asp:ImageButton>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function clickFn(e) {
    $("#aspButton").click();
}
```

The click event of "aspButton" is [almost] never triggered when I click on "mButton". I have tried binding to the "mButton" touchend event but this also does not work.

How would I be able to use an anchor tag with the data-role="button" attribute to fire the click event of an asp button? I am using the latest Kendo UI Mobile and latest JQuery.

Thanks!

**Update**

It works perfectly if I change my clickFn to the following:

```
function clickFn(e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#aspButton").click();
    }, 400);
}
```

This is leading me to believe Kendo UI Mobile's event handling may have something to do with this that I am unaware of. According to their forums, the Kendo UI Mobile View transition speeds is 400ms. Further, setting the timeout to even 399ms fails to execute the aspButton click event successfully.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure if the '**aspButton**' is actually the id of the widget on the client side? (I personally have doubts about this)

You can try to trigger the event with the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method jQuery provides.

Comment: I know I can trigger the click event using .click() from jquery... Also is there a way to determine the client side ID then? I'm not too savvy with asp Net but the DOM does show the ID here as aspButton

Comment: Similar question is covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776789/find-out-client-side-id-of-html-element-created-by-net

Comment: Thanks for the link, I feel more confident now, but the problem still persists.